# Python ProcessPoolExecutor not saving all files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency, multiprocessing

I have a very simple ProcessPoolExecutor script that uses a separate crawler class I built (named "crawler" in the code) to simply fetch a webpage and save the HTML.

The problem is, even though I know that ~85% of the document requests are completing successfully, I'm only ending up with 15-20% of the files that should have been saved.

Is there some glaring mistake here that I'm not seeing? I'm self-taught, so be gentle with me.

```
def crawl(current_url):

    if current_url in crawled:
        return

    crawled.append(current_url)
    
    try:
        crawler.crawl(current_url, use_session=False, timeout=20)
        # crawler is my html retrieval class
    except Exception as e:
        print ('Exception ocurred  on {}:'.format(current_url))
        print(e)

    print ('Fetched: {} bytes.'.format(str(len(crawler.content))))

    today = date.today()
    filename = site + ' - ' + today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + ' ' + title + '.html'
    # Filename is always unique
    with open(filename, 'w') as html_out:
        html_out.write(today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + ' @ ' + current_url + '\n')
        html_out.write(str(crawler.soup))
        # crawler.soup is a BeautifulSoup object

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    freeze_support()

    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as worker:
        
        for url in list_of_urls
            
            worker.submit(crawl, url)
```

And I had the same problem with concurrent.futures, and both with saving the html in the function, and with returning it and saving outside the function.

Comment: Unfortunately there's not enough of your code to be able to tell where you've gone wrong. Some of what you have shown is syntactically incorrect

Comment: If you can tell me what more I need to add, I will

Comment: Just show the code that you're having trouble with. As it stands, the code you've presented is not runnable